# Following Buddhist concepts in non Buddhist society

Tags: personal-practice, karma, society

How do you reconcile Buddhist concepts/faith in a non-Buddhist society? For example if you live in a society where you are to kill(stray or sick animals) or expected to lie as part of your livelihood?

If you aren't able to leave, how does participating in these forced actions effect your karma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I live in a non- Buddhist society and it is true that in order to earn your livelihood you are expected to kill animals or lie. This is not the ideal situation. But there is hope , if you keep meditating on what Buddha said then you will understand that you can live without attachments to money , job or relationship.

Ideally one should quit and become a monk but the circumstances are such that there is no place or people left to seriously consider the implications of Buddhas teaching.

So keep in touch with Buddha and live your life with desires of renunciation one day. Admit that one day you will have to let go of your belongings and relationships because you are not body , not feelings , not perceptions , not choices , not consciousness.
Once you have understood this be happy because now you know the Truth.

Comment: This is true. However the karma we create will likely trump that knowledge right?

Comment: @TruthSeeker yes it creates bad karma if you lie or kill. Try avoiding that. If possible change your job. Do not lie out of your own craving.Buddha has said one should not lie even for a joke.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't worked a job for 8 years due to an increasingly politically correct workplace, I have never had to lie in any job. It is a matter of finding a job where you are not required to lie. Also, I have never had to put down any animals because I do not keep pets.

Comment: Perhaps if you had stayed in the PC workplace and did not have the option to leave, lieing may have been necessary?

Comment: Not possible for me to lie. Better to die on your feet than to live on your knees. I was 'pushed' to leave my former job, They no longer wanted people like me. I chose to leave. While the Buddhist internet space is largely PC, this is unrelated to real Buddhism.